# Incorrect date format

Tags: excel

I have pulled data from Oracle tool but the date format is coming along with time whereas I just need the date in mmddyyyy or mmddyyyy format. I have tried changing the format of the date. It shows the date as correct but in formula bar the date is still incorrect. Please advice.

Comment: What happens when you change cell format to `Number`?

Answer (score 0):

The formula bar shows the underlying text without the formatting, changing the cell formatting does not change the data, if you want data in another format you should probably look if you can change the way your tool exports it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the date is still being shown in the original Oracle format in the formula bar is because all you have done is changed the formatting, which is how the data appears in the Worksheet.  If you want to change the underlying data, you can do the following:

```
 =TEXT(A1,"mmddyyyy")
```

Where A1 is a cell containing a date from your Oracle source, and the formula is in say cell B1.

But B1 now has a formula, which may not be want you want either.  If you want text in your desired format, you have to then copy cell B1 and do a **paste special**:

```
ALT + E + S
```

Choose "Values" from the dialog box in another cell, and you should have the Oracle data in the format you want it.

Comment: Hi Tim, Your help worked wonders perfect. Thanks a ton for helping.